# Construct a constant array depending on a boolean

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list of React components as follows.

```
  const myBoolean = // some logic

  const myArray = [
    {
      Component: <MyComponent1/>,
    },
    {
      Component: <MyComponent2/>,
    },
    {
      Component: <MyComponent3/>,
    },
  ];
```

For MyComponent2, I only want to add it to the list based on myBoolean's value.
Is there a clean way to do this without any need to loop or using let to construct 1 by 1?

I can't do something like the following as it is in valid syntax.

```
  const myArray = [
    {
      Component: <MyComponent1/>,
    },
    {myBoolean &&{
      Component: <MyComponent2/>,
    }},
    {
      Component: <MyComponent3/>,
    },
  ];
```

Trying to avoid this alternative.

```
let myArray = [];
myArray.push({Component: <MyComponent1/>,},);
if (myBoolean) myArray.push({Component: <MyComponent3/>,},);
myArray.push({Component: <MyComponent3/>,},);
```

Comment: `const addIn = myBoolean ? [{ p: (<C />) }] : []; const myArray = [1, ...addIn, 2, 3, 4];` would be an option, if you really want that inline style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to not alter the array after you've defined it in a condition that depends on the index. Rather, use

```
const myArray = [
  {
    Component: <MyComponent1/>,
  },
  myBoolean ? {
    Component: <MyComponent2/>,
  } : null,
  {
    Component: <MyComponent3/>,
  },
].filter(Boolean);
```

or

```
const myArray = [
  {
    Component: <MyComponent1/>,
    condition: true,
  },
  {
    Component: <MyComponent2/>,
    condition: myBoolean,
  },
  {
    Component: <MyComponent3/>,
    condition: true,
  },
].filter(o => o.condition);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about conditionally remove the item?

```
let myArray = [
    {
      Component: <MyComponent1/>,
      key 1
    },
    {
      Component: <MyComponent2/>, 
      key: 2
    },
    {
      Component: <MyComponent3/>,
      key: 3
    },
  ];
```

myArray.filter( item => item.key !== 2 ) //base on conditions

Comment: I don't want to pass in a null, just don't want to add Component if false.

Comment: there's not a good way if you want to use array and yet want to insert it at a specific position. Probably better to think out of the box, and  **conditionally remove** the object instead. e.g. using array.filter

Comment: I could still work around MyComponent2 being appended at the end if there is a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Array.prototype.splice` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

e.g.

```
if (myBoolean) {
   myArray.splice(index, 0, { Component: <MyComponent2 />})
}
```

just beware that splice *changes* the content of the array, therefore since you are using this in React, it shouldn't be used by itself if the array is used as a state property, i.e. you'd have to create a new reference first if it was used with state, e.g.

```
if (myBoolean) {
   myArray = myArray.slice(0)
   myArray.splice(index, 0, { Component: <MyComponent2 />})
}
```